# Form sending email but in the email $_POST values are blank

Tags: php, json, email, post

I have read many forums where this exact question posted but there is no satisfactory answer. Some posts seem to have found out how to make it work but the answer is not shared or only partly answered.

the answer that i see the most is (but don't know how to use it):

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {'use strict',
    $this = $(this);
    $.post("sendemail.php", $(".contact-form").serialize(),function(result){
    if(result.type == 'success'){
        $this.prev().text(result.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    }
});
    return false;
});
```

the problem with this is that $_POST is not being sent. The mail function is working but the mail contents are blank

my mail message:

```
Name: 
Email:  
Subject: 
Message:
```

exactly this is in my mail when I fill the form with data and nothing is being sent

main.html

```
<h4>Contact Form</h4>
<div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" required="required" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" required placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

sendemail.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Email sent!'
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'myEmail@gmail.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

Comment: Check data, sended to server, maybe problem in js

Comment: Did you check your network tab on dev tools to make sure the correct request is being made? Next, did you `print_r` the value of `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your form possibly getting submitted twice? (once completed and then blank) The html form is already fully wired to POST without the use of the submit handler, which is redundant.

If I'm going to submit a form via AJAX, I typically set only the id of the form (i.e. no action and no method attributes) and I use a regular button (not submit) as the submit button.  This makes it clear that jQuery will be handling the POSTing.

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" role="form">
    ...fields
    <button id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then in jQuery

```
'use strict';
var form = $('.contact-form'),
    btn_submit = $('#btn_submit');

btn_submit.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default button behavior
    $.post('sendemail.php', form.serialize(),function(result){
    if(result.type == 'success'){
        form.prev().text(result.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just tried this. Doesn't work. The form is not sent (button does not respond after being pressed). I pasted this inside the <head></head> tags and have the jquery library. Don't know if I messed up somewhere. The button also has the id="btn-submit" @rmirablle

Comment: 2 quick suggestions: 1) the example I gave has `btn_submit` not `btn-submit` and 2) make sure you wire up the jquery inside the document ready callback, e.g. `$().ready(function() {});`

Answer (score 0):

Change your "jquery" code as shown below:

```
$('.contact-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent default form 'submit' event
    $this = $(this);
    $.post(
      "sendemail.php",
       $(".contact-form").serialize(),
       function(result){
          if(result.type == 'success'){
              $this.prev().text(result.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
          }           
       },
       'json'  // expecting a JSON response from server
    );
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the email that gets sent out doesn't have the right fields, you seem to be addressing the fact that the OP didn't explicitly set `json` as the return type. Note that `jQuery` guesses the return type anyway, and you should only use what you suggested if you cannot set your server to specify the response type.

Comment: @JuanMendes, I did not pointed that problem is "unspecified return type"(it's just for convenience). `sendemail.php` seems to be almost correct. So I've suggested a readable jquery code.

Comment: I just tried this. Same problem as rmirabelle's answer. The button does not respond. @Roman

Comment: "The button does not respond" - what "button response" do you expect certainly?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I mean the submit button `<button id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>`

Comment: start debugging: put `console.log($(".contact-form").serialize())` right before sending post request, and tell the output

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple forms with the css class .contact-form in the same page. If you want to submit this form, then you can use form id selector.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#main-contact-form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();  // prevent default form 'submit' event
            var $this = $(this);
            $.post("sendemail.php", $this.serialize(), function(result) {
                if (result.type == 'success') {
                    $this.prev().text(result.message)
                         .fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
</script>
```

Or you can write the code using the css selector as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.contact-form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();  // prevent default form 'submit' event
            var $this = $(this);
            $.post("sendemail.php", $this.serialize(), function(result) {
                if (result.type == 'success') {
                    $this.prev().text(result.message)
                         .fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
</script>
```